What do I need to upgrade/expand my HPE DL360 Gen9 with 8x SFF to 10x SFF
I probably made a mistake:
I bought a HPE DL360 Gen9 with 8x SFF and 1 DVD-Drive. I've seen there are DL360 with 10x SFF. Therefor what componentes do I need to upgrade/expand my 8xSFF to a 10xSFF?
Of course I am aware I'll lose the DVD-Drive.
I do have already a spare P840 controller from a spare server which I might use.
Thank you

Probably a new drive cage. However, your hardware is EoL, and we generally don't support that.
